# It doesn't say how to make in-line quotes in the help bar

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Yes, it already says how to make blockquotes

> like this.

However, I have noticed the lack of help how to make `in-line quotes like this.`

If you are wondering what the help bar is, it is the "How to format" section that you see when typing a question.

Answer (score 6):

Those aren't inline quotes; **please don't use them as quotes!** That's code formatting, and it should *only be used for code* and will likely be edited out of your posts if you (ab)use it in a different way.

(By the way, that is indeed covered [in the Help Center](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), albeit only in the "comment formatting" section. It's also covered in the small drop-down on the questions page...

> [image: dropdown]

... which you can view by clicking the "?" button.)